# VUE: Is it possible to have property name data without conflicts?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

so I have many components that takes :data to seed them

so imagine this example:

```
<Comp1 :data="apiResponse.comp1"></Comp1>
<Comp2 :data="somedata"></Comp2>
<Comp3 :data="apiResponse.comp3"></Comp3>
```

and in my component(s) I have something like this

```
export default class Comp1 extends Vue {
  @Prop() public data!: IModel[];

  data() {
    return {
      prop1: 0,
      prop2: null, ...
    }
 }
}
```

Obviously I am getting an error that "data" is defined twice.

So how can I still keep using :data as component's property without conflicts and breaking anything?

Comment: On typescript you don't need `data()`, remove data and use `public prop1: number;`

Comment: @max is it going to be reactive as well then?

Comment: Of course.......